# Copy files into a directory using call systems

Tags: c, file, system-calls

I have a program that take two files Source and Destination. 
I am trying to Copies the SOURCE file to the DESTINATION file. If DESTINATION does not exist, it is created. If DESTINATION exists and is a file, it is overwritten. **If DESTINATION exists and is a directory, the source files will be copied there**.

How can i copy the source file into the destination directory using calls system ?

What i tried :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "checksum.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: lcp [-b taille] source... destination\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0644); //0644 — owner can read or write, group and others can only read; or something more restrictive).
    if (fd1 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    int fd2 = open(argv[2], O_RDWR|O_CREAT);  
    if (fd2 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading and writing\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd1);  
    close(fd2);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a loop that does a `read` on a buffer and a `write` of that buffer.

Note that most of the time if you ask `read` to get (e.g.) 100 bytes, it will do so for most files. It may return less than that, particularly if the file size is *not* a multiple of 100. So, we must account for "short" reads (and errors). Likewise for `write`

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
//#include "checksum.h"

// xread -- read in data (account for short reads and errors)
// RETURNS: number of bytes read
ssize_t
xread(int fd,void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    unsigned char *bp = buf;
    ssize_t curlen;
    ssize_t totlen = 0;

    // continue reading until end of buffer or read error
    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= curlen, totlen += curlen) {
        // read next chunk
        // NOTE: curlen may be less than buflen
        curlen = read(fd,&bp[totlen],buflen);

        // got an EOF
        if (curlen == 0)
            break;

        // read error
        if (curlen < 0) {
            // handle interruptions from signals
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                curlen = 0;
                continue;
            }
            perror("xread");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return totlen;
}

// xwrite -- write out data (account for short reads and errors)
// RETURNS: number of bytes written
ssize_t
xwrite(int fd,const void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    const unsigned char *bp = buf;
    ssize_t curlen;
    ssize_t totlen = 0;

    // continue writing until end of buffer or write error
    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= curlen, totlen += curlen) {
        // write next chunk
        // NOTE: curlen may be less than buflen
        curlen = write(fd,&bp[totlen],buflen);

        // got EOF (NOTE: this should _never_ happen)
        if (curlen == 0)
            break;

        // write error
        if (curlen < 0) {
            // handle interruptions from signals
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                curlen = 0;
                continue;
            }
            perror("xwrite");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return totlen;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: lcp [-b taille] source... destination\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // 0644 — owner can read or write, group and others can only read; or
    // something more restrictive).
    int fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0644);
    if (fd1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading\n",
            argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    int fd2 = open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd2 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading and writing\n",
            argv[0], argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through files and copy bytes
    unsigned char buf[64 * 1024];
    while (1) {
        ssize_t rlen = xread(fd1,buf,sizeof(buf));
        if (rlen <= 0)
            break;
        xwrite(fd2,buf,rlen);
    }

    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);

    return 0;
}
```

*Note:* As Andrew pointed out, the `open` with `O_CREAT` needs a mode argument

---

**UPDATE:**

> If destination is a directory, the code fails spectacularly. And don't just say failed to open. Please strerror the reason. – –
> user58697

Yes, I only added the `read/write` loop since that was the main problem.

> @user58697 I had the same problem that blocked me, do you have any idea how to fix this... –
> elfii

Okay, there are a few ways to solve this (which was part of the original problem that I missed):

1. Use `stat` on the output file to decide if it's a directory
2. Check `errno` from the open and see if it's `EISDIR`

While both are valid, I chose (2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
//#include "checksum.h"

// xread -- read in data (account for short reads and errors)
// RETURNS: number of bytes read
ssize_t
xread(int fd,void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    unsigned char *bp = buf;
    ssize_t curlen;
    ssize_t totlen = 0;

    // continue reading until end of buffer or read error
    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= curlen, totlen += curlen) {
        // read next chunk
        // NOTE: curlen may be less than buflen
        curlen = read(fd,&bp[totlen],buflen);

        // got an EOF
        if (curlen == 0)
            break;

        // read error
        if (curlen < 0) {
            // handle interruptions from signals
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                curlen = 0;
                continue;
            }
            perror("xread");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return totlen;
}

// xwrite -- write out data (account for short reads and errors)
// RETURNS: number of bytes written
ssize_t
xwrite(int fd,const void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    const unsigned char *bp = buf;
    ssize_t curlen;
    ssize_t totlen = 0;

    // continue writing until end of buffer or write error
    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= curlen, totlen += curlen) {
        // write next chunk
        // NOTE: curlen may be less than buflen
        curlen = write(fd,&bp[totlen],buflen);

        // got EOF (NOTE: this should _never_ happen)
        if (curlen == 0)
            break;

        // write error
        if (curlen < 0) {
            // handle interruptions from signals
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                curlen = 0;
                continue;
            }
            perror("xwrite");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return totlen;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: lcp [-b taille] source... destination\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // input file
    char *ifile = argv[1];
    char *itail = ifile;
    int fd1;

    // output file
    char *otail = argv[2];
    char ofile[strlen(otail) + 1 + strlen(ifile) + 1];
    int fd2;

    // 0644 — owner can read or write, group and others can only read; or
    // something more restrictive).
    fd1 = open(ifile, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading -- %s\n",
            argv[0], itail, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // try original output file and then [if directory] the concatenated file
    for (int tryno = 1;  tryno <= 2;  ++tryno) {
        // open output assuming arg is flat file
        fd2 = open(otail, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
        if (fd2 >= 0)
            break;

        // if output is not a directory, there is another error
        if (errno != EISDIR)
            break;

        // get file tail from input file
        // (e.g. foo/bar --> bar
        itail = strrchr(ifile,'/');
        if (itail != NULL)
            ++itail;
        else
            itail = ifile;

        // create output file: otail / itail
        strcpy(ofile,otail);
        strcat(ofile,"/");
        strcat(ofile,itail);

        otail = ofile;
    }

    // stop if output could not be opened
    if (fd2 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for writing -- %s\n",
            argv[0], otail, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through files and copy bytes
    unsigned char buf[64 * 1024];
    while (1) {
        ssize_t rlen = xread(fd1,buf,sizeof(buf));
        if (rlen <= 0)
            break;
        xwrite(fd2,buf,rlen);
    }

    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> the only problem is when the source file is the same as destination, it returns an empty file (I want it to return the destination file with the same content of the source file) –
> elfii

If the output file is the *same* file as the input file, we want to *suppress* the `open` of the output file and *not* copy any data. (i.e.) The output file already has the data. If we attempt the copy, the `open` for the output will truncate/destroy the input file and we get a zero file as a result.

In the previous method, we could check for `EISDIR` or do `stat`. Now, we *must* do `stat`. It is *nondestructive* so we can use it *before* doing `open` on the output file.

It is *not* sufficient merely to compare the strings that are the file paths. We must use data from the `stat` syscall to handle cases such as:

```
# simple -- strings are the same
cp A A

# same file but strings are different
cp A ./A

# same file but strings are different
cp A `pwd`/A

# strings are different but the files are the same inode
ln A B
cp A B

# strings are different but B is a symlink to A
ln -s A B
cp A B
```

Files [under linux/POSIX] are the same *if*:

1. Both the `st_dev` and `st_ino` are the same.
2. That is, they are on the same device/filesystem and they are the same inode ("information node") within the given FS.
3. Inode numbers are *unique* for any file *data* in a given FS even if the two files are *hard* links of one another.

Here is the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
//#include "checksum.h"

// xread -- read in data (account for short reads and errors)
// RETURNS: number of bytes read
ssize_t
xread(int fd,void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    unsigned char *bp = buf;
    ssize_t curlen;
    ssize_t totlen = 0;

    // continue reading until end of buffer or read error
    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= curlen, totlen += curlen) {
        // read next chunk
        // NOTE: curlen may be less than buflen
        curlen = read(fd,&bp[totlen],buflen);

        // got an EOF
        if (curlen == 0)
            break;

        // read error
        if (curlen < 0) {
            // handle interruptions from signals
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                curlen = 0;
                continue;
            }
            perror("xread");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return totlen;
}

// xwrite -- write out data (account for short reads and errors)
// RETURNS: number of bytes written
ssize_t
xwrite(int fd,const void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    const unsigned char *bp = buf;
    ssize_t curlen;
    ssize_t totlen = 0;

    // continue writing until end of buffer or write error
    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= curlen, totlen += curlen) {
        // write next chunk
        // NOTE: curlen may be less than buflen
        curlen = write(fd,&bp[totlen],buflen);

        // got EOF (NOTE: this should _never_ happen)
        if (curlen == 0)
            break;

        // write error
        if (curlen < 0) {
            // handle interruptions from signals
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                curlen = 0;
                continue;
            }
            perror("xwrite");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return totlen;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: lcp [-b taille] source... destination\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // input file
    char *ifile = argv[1];
    char *itail = ifile;
    int fd1 = -1;
    struct stat st1;

    // output file
    char *otail = argv[2];
    char ofile[strlen(otail) + 1 + strlen(ifile) + 1];
    int fd2 = -1;
    struct stat st2;

    int err;

    fd1 = open(ifile, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading -- %s\n",
            argv[0], itail, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // stat the input file
    err = fstat(fd1,&st1);
    if (err < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to stat file %s for reading -- %s\n",
            argv[0], itail, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    int outnot = 0;
    int outflags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT;

    // try original output file and then [if directory] the concatenated file
    for (int tryno = 1;  tryno <= 2;  ++tryno) {
        // assume we may open the output file
        outnot = 0;

        // get info on [existing] output file
        err = stat(otail,&st2);

        // file does not exist -- we may open it
        if (err < 0)
            break;

        // check for input and output being the same file
        // if they're the same, do _not_ open the output file as we'd truncate
        // and destroy the original
        outnot = ((st1.st_dev == st2.st_dev) && (st1.st_ino == st2.st_ino));
        if (outnot)
            break;

        // get the type of the file
        int ftyp = st2.st_mode & S_IFMT;

        // output file is _not_ a directory -- use the filename
        if (ftyp != S_IFDIR) {
            // only truncate ordinary files (not devices, pipes, sockets)
            // NOTE: this may or may not be a good restriction
            if (ftyp == S_IFREG)
                outflags |= O_TRUNC;
            break;
        }

        // get file tail from input file
        // (e.g. foo/bar --> bar
        itail = strrchr(ifile,'/');
        if (itail != NULL)
            ++itail;
        else
            itail = ifile;

        // create output file: otail / itail
        strcpy(ofile,otail);
        strcat(ofile,"/");
        strcat(ofile,itail);

        otail = ofile;
    }

    // open output file and copy over input file contents
    do {
        // we may _not_ open output file (i.e. _no_ copying)
        if (outnot)
            break;

        // open output assuming arg is flat file
        // 0644 — owner can read or write, group and others can only read; or
        // something more restrictive).
        fd2 = open(otail, outflags, 0644);
        if (fd2 >= 0)
            break;

        // stop if output could not be opened
        if (fd2 < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for writing -- %s\n",
                argv[0], otail, strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }

        // loop through files and copy bytes
        unsigned char buf[64 * 1024];
        while (1) {
            ssize_t rlen = xread(fd1,buf,sizeof(buf));
            if (rlen <= 0)
                break;
            xwrite(fd2,buf,rlen);
        }
    } while (0);

    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

> i get the same problem in the last update, If DESTINATION exists and is a directory, the source files will be copied there. –
> elfii

I believe the previous code handles this case.

But ...

1. There was a bug. It had an extraneous `if (fd2 >= 0) break;`.
2. The program would/could only handle a *single* input file. So, `cp A B C` would fail even if `C` was a directory.

Supporting multiple input files required some refactoring. And, I've added some debug printing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
//#include "checksum.h"

int opt_v;
char *pgmname;

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    fprintf(stderr,_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

// input file
char *ifile;
char *itail;
int fdinp;
struct stat stinp;

// output file
char *oarg;
char *otail;
char ofile[1024];
int otyp;
int fdout = -1;
struct stat stout;
int outnot;

// xread -- read in data (account for short reads and errors)
// RETURNS: number of bytes read
ssize_t
xread(int fd,void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    unsigned char *bp = buf;
    ssize_t curlen;
    ssize_t totlen = 0;

    // continue reading until end of buffer or read error
    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= curlen, totlen += curlen) {
        // read next chunk
        // NOTE: curlen may be less than buflen
        curlen = read(fd,&bp[totlen],buflen);

        // got an EOF
        if (curlen == 0)
            break;

        // read error
        if (curlen < 0) {
            // handle interruptions from signals
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                curlen = 0;
                continue;
            }
            perror("xread");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return totlen;
}

// xwrite -- write out data (account for short reads and errors)
// RETURNS: number of bytes written
ssize_t
xwrite(int fd,const void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    const unsigned char *bp = buf;
    ssize_t curlen;
    ssize_t totlen = 0;

    // continue writing until end of buffer or write error
    for (;  buflen > 0;  buflen -= curlen, totlen += curlen) {
        // write next chunk
        // NOTE: curlen may be less than buflen
        curlen = write(fd,&bp[totlen],buflen);

        // got EOF (NOTE: this should _never_ happen)
        if (curlen == 0)
            break;

        // write error
        if (curlen < 0) {
            // handle interruptions from signals
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                curlen = 0;
                continue;
            }
            perror("xwrite");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return totlen;
}

int
dofile(void)
{
    int err;

    // open the input file
    fdinp = open(ifile, O_RDONLY);
    if (fdinp < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading -- %s\n",
            pgmname, ifile, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    // stat the input file
    err = fstat(fdinp,&stinp);
    if (err < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to stat file %s for reading -- %s\n",
            pgmname, ifile, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    outnot = 0;
    int outflags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT;

    // try original output file and then [if directory] the concatenated
    // file
    otail = oarg;
    for (int tryno = 1;  tryno <= 2;  ++tryno) {
        // assume we may open the output file
        outnot = 0;

        // get info on [existing] output file
        dbgprt("dofile: TRY tryno=%d otail='%s'\n",tryno,otail);
        err = stat(otail,&stout);

        // file does not exist -- we may open it
        if (err < 0)
            break;

        // check for input and output being the same file
        // if they're the same, do _not_ open the output file as we'd
        // truncate and destroy the original
        outnot = ((stinp.st_dev == stout.st_dev) &&
            (stinp.st_ino == stout.st_ino));
        dbgprt("dofile: CMP outnot=%d stinp=%ld/%ld stout=%ld/%ld\n",
            outnot,stinp.st_dev,stinp.st_ino,stout.st_dev,stout.st_ino);
        if (outnot)
            break;

        // output file is _not_ a directory -- use the filename
        if (otyp != S_IFDIR) {
            // only truncate ordinary files (not devices, pipes, sockets)
            // NOTE: this may or may not be a good restriction
            if (otyp == S_IFREG) {
                dbgprt("dofile: TRUNC\n");
                outflags |= O_TRUNC;
            }
            break;
        }

        dbgprt("dofile: ISDIR\n");

        // get file tail from input file
        // (e.g. foo/bar --> bar
        itail = strrchr(ifile,'/');
        if (itail != NULL)
            ++itail;
        else
            itail = ifile;

        // create output file: otail / itail
        strcpy(ofile,otail);
        strcat(ofile,"/");
        strcat(ofile,itail);
        dbgprt("dofile: OFILE ofile='%s'\n",ofile);

        otail = ofile;
    }

    // open output file and copy over input file contents
    do {
        fdout = -1;

        // we may _not_ open output file (i.e. _no_ copying)
        if (outnot)
            break;

        // open output assuming arg is flat file
        // 0644 — owner can read or write, group and others can only read; or
        // something more restrictive).
        dbgprt("dofile: OPENOUT otail='%s' outflags=%8.8X\n",otail,outflags);
        fdout = open(otail, outflags, 0644);

        // stop if output could not be opened
        if (fdout < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for writing -- %s\n",
                pgmname, otail, strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }

        // loop through files and copy bytes
        unsigned char buf[64 * 1024];
        while (1) {
            ssize_t rlen = xread(fdinp,buf,sizeof(buf));
            dbgprt("dofile: COPY rlen=%zd\n",rlen);
            if (rlen <= 0)
                break;
            xwrite(fdout,buf,rlen);
        }
    } while (0);

    close(fdinp);
    fdinp = -1;

    close(fdout);
    fdout = -1;

    return outnot;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // get program name
    pgmname = *argv;
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    // handle options
    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch(cp[-1]) {
        case 'v':
            opt_v = ! opt_v;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: lcp [-b taille] source... destination\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // get target file name
    oarg = argv[argc - 1];

    // check target
    int err = stat(oarg,&stout);
    if (err < 0)
        otyp = -1;
    else
        otyp = stout.st_mode & S_IFMT;

    // we just want input files
    --argc;

    // with more than one input file ensure target is a directory
    if ((argc > 1) && (otyp != S_IFDIR)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: target file '%s' is not a directory\n",
            pgmname, oarg);
        return 3;
    }

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        ifile = *argv;
        dofile();
        if (outnot)
            break;
    }

    return outnot ? 2 : 0;
}
```

One of the issues is that I did not create any tests. The above was based purely on a clean compilation but *no* testing.

So, I've created a `dotest` [perl] script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# dotest -- perform tests

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;

    while (@argv > 0) {
        $opt = $argv[0];
        last unless ($opt =~ s/^-//);
        shift(@argv);

        last if ($opt eq "-");

        if ($opt =~ /^([^=]+)=(.+)$/) {
            ($sym,$val) = ($1,$2);
        }
        else {
            ($sym,$val) = ($opt,1);
        }

        $sym = "opt_" . $sym;
        $$sym = $val;
    }

    ###$topdir = "/tmp/copy";
    $topdir = $ENV{PWD};
    ###xchdir($topdir);
    zprtx("TOPDIR %s\n",$topdir);

    $tail = shift(@argv);
    $tail //= "fix5";

    push(@cflags,"-g");
    push(@cflags,"-DDEBUG")
        if ($opt_d);
    push(@cflags,"-Wall","-Werror");
    $code = doexec("cc",@cflags,"-o",$tail,"$tail.c");
    exit(1) if ($code);
    $xfile = "$topdir/$tail";

    $workdir = "$topdir/work";
    sysrmdir($workdir);
    xmkdir($workdir);
    xchdir($workdir);

    test("noexist","B does not exist");
    clean();
    touch("A");
    copy(0);

    test("exist","B does exist");
    copy(0);

    test("AA1","target is A");
    copy(2,"A","A");

    test("AA2","target is A with different name");
    copy(2,"A","./A");

    test("mkdir","B is a directory");
    clean("B");
    doexec("mkdir","-p","B");
    copy(0);

    test("mkdir2","B is a directory (multiple files)");
    clean("B");
    touch("C");
    doexec("mkdir","-p","B");
    copy(0,"A","C","B");

    test("notdir1","target must be directory but does not exist");
    copy(3,"A","C","D");

    test("notdir2","target must be directory but is file");
    touch("D");
    copy(3,"A","C","D");

    test("hardlink","B is a hardlink to A");
    clean("B");
    doexec("ln","A","B");
    copy(2);

    test("symlink","B is a symlink to A");
    clean("B");
    doexec("ln","-s","A","B");
    copy(2);
}

sub test
{
    my($name,$reason) = @_;

    zprtx("\n");
    zprtx("%s\n","-" x 80);
    zprtx("test: %s -- %s\n",$name,$reason);
}

sub clean
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($tail);

    @argv = dirload(".")
        if (@argv <= 0);

    foreach $tail (@argv) {
        zprtx("clean: %s\n",$tail);
        sysrmdir($tail);
    }
}

sub touch
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($tail,$xfdst);

    @argv = qw("A")
        if (@argv <= 0);

    foreach $tail (@argv) {
        zprtx("touch: %s\n",$tail);
        open($xfdst,">$tail") or
            die("touch: unable to open '$tail' -- $!\n");
        printf($xfdst "i am %s\n",$tail);
        close($xfdst);
    }
}

sub copy
{
    my(@files) = @_;
    my($expcode);
    my($cmd);
    my($actcode);

    $expcode = shift(@files);
    zprtx("copy: expected status is %d\n",$expcode);

    push(@files,"A","B")
        if (@files <= 0);

    $cmd = join(" ",@files);
    zprtx("copy: FILES %s\n",$cmd);

    unshift(@files,$xfile);
    unshift(@files,"qgdb")
        if ($opt_gdb);

    $actcode = doexec(@files);
    zprtx("copy: STATUS %d\n",$actcode);

    doexec("ls","-lRi");

    if ($actcode != $expcode) {
        zprtx("copy: expected code %d but got %d\n",$expcode,$actcode);
        exit(1);
    }
}

sub dirload
{
    my($dir) = @_;
    my($xfdir);
    my($tail);
    my(@tails);

    opendir($xfdir,$dir) or
        die("dirload: unable to open '$dir' -- $!\n");

    while (1) {
        $tail = readdir($xfdir);
        last unless (defined($tail));

        next if ($tail eq ".");
        next if ($tail eq "..");

        push(@tails,$tail);
    }

    closedir($xfdir);

    @tails = sort(@tails);

    @tails;
}

sub doexec
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($cmd);
    my($code);

    $cmd = join(" ",@argv);
    zprtx("doexec: %s\n",$cmd);

    system($cmd);
    $code = $? >> 8;

    $code;
}

sub zprtx
{

    printf(STDERR @_);
}

sub sysrmdir
{
    my($dir) = @_;

    doexec("rm","-fr",$dir)
        if (-e $dir);
}

sub xmkdir
{
    my($dir) = @_;

    doexec("mkdir","-p",$dir)
        unless (-d $dir);
}

sub xchdir
{
    my($dir) = @_;

    zprtx("xchdir: %s\n",$dir);
    chdir($dir) or
        die("xchdir: unable to cd to '$dir' -- $!\n");
}
```

Here is the output of the script:

```
TOPDIR /tmp/copy
doexec: cc -g -DDEBUG -Wall -Werror -o fix5 fix5.c
doexec: rm -fr /tmp/copy/work
doexec: mkdir -p /tmp/copy/work
xchdir: /tmp/copy/work

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: noexist -- B does not exist
touch: A
copy: expected status is 0
copy: FILES A B
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A B
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='B'
dofile: OPENOUT otail='B' outflags=00000041
dofile: COPY rlen=7
dofile: COPY rlen=0
copy: STATUS 0
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 8
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764494 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 B

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: exist -- B does exist
copy: expected status is 0
copy: FILES A B
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A B
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='B'
dofile: CMP outnot=0 stinp=46/218760020 stout=46/218764494
dofile: TRUNC
dofile: OPENOUT otail='B' outflags=00000241
dofile: COPY rlen=7
dofile: COPY rlen=0
copy: STATUS 0
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 8
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764494 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 B

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: AA1 -- target is A
copy: expected status is 2
copy: FILES A A
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A A
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='A'
dofile: CMP outnot=1 stinp=46/218760020 stout=46/218760020
copy: STATUS 2
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 8
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764494 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 B

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: AA2 -- target is A with different name
copy: expected status is 2
copy: FILES A ./A
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A ./A
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='./A'
dofile: CMP outnot=1 stinp=46/218760020 stout=46/218760020
copy: STATUS 2
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 8
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764494 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 B

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: mkdir -- B is a directory
clean: B
doexec: rm -fr B
doexec: mkdir -p B
copy: expected status is 0
copy: FILES A B
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A B
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='B'
dofile: CMP outnot=0 stinp=46/218760020 stout=46/218764511
dofile: ISDIR
dofile: OFILE ofile='B/A'
dofile: TRY tryno=2 otail='B/A'
dofile: OPENOUT otail='B/A' outflags=00000041
dofile: COPY rlen=7
dofile: COPY rlen=0
copy: STATUS 0
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 4
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764511 drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 60 Sep 29 14:45 B

./B:
total 4
218764512 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: mkdir2 -- B is a directory (multiple files)
clean: B
doexec: rm -fr B
touch: C
doexec: mkdir -p B
copy: expected status is 0
copy: FILES A C B
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A C B
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='B'
dofile: CMP outnot=0 stinp=46/218760020 stout=46/218764517
dofile: ISDIR
dofile: OFILE ofile='B/A'
dofile: TRY tryno=2 otail='B/A'
dofile: OPENOUT otail='B/A' outflags=00000041
dofile: COPY rlen=7
dofile: COPY rlen=0
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='B'
dofile: CMP outnot=0 stinp=46/218760034 stout=46/218764517
dofile: ISDIR
dofile: OFILE ofile='B/C'
dofile: TRY tryno=2 otail='B/C'
dofile: OPENOUT otail='B/C' outflags=00000041
dofile: COPY rlen=7
dofile: COPY rlen=0
copy: STATUS 0
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 8
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764517 drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 80 Sep 29 14:45 B
218760034 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  7 Sep 29 14:45 C

./B:
total 8
218764518 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764519 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 C

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: notdir1 -- target must be directory but does not exist
copy: expected status is 3
copy: FILES A C D
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A C D
/tmp/copy/fix5: target file 'D' is not a directory
copy: STATUS 3
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 8
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764517 drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 80 Sep 29 14:45 B
218760034 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  7 Sep 29 14:45 C

./B:
total 8
218764518 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764519 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 C

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: notdir2 -- target must be directory but is file
touch: D
copy: expected status is 3
copy: FILES A C D
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A C D
/tmp/copy/fix5: target file 'D' is not a directory
copy: STATUS 3
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 12
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764517 drwxr-xr-x. 2 user user 80 Sep 29 14:45 B
218760034 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  7 Sep 29 14:45 C
218760040 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user  7 Sep 29 14:45 D

./B:
total 8
218764518 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764519 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 C

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: hardlink -- B is a hardlink to A
clean: B
doexec: rm -fr B
doexec: ln A B
copy: expected status is 2
copy: FILES A B
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A B
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='B'
dofile: CMP outnot=1 stinp=46/218760020 stout=46/218760020
copy: STATUS 2
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 16
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 2 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 2 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 B
218760034 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 C
218760040 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 D

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test: symlink -- B is a symlink to A
clean: B
doexec: rm -fr B
doexec: ln -s A B
copy: expected status is 2
copy: FILES A B
doexec: /tmp/copy/fix5 A B
dofile: TRY tryno=1 otail='B'
dofile: CMP outnot=1 stinp=46/218760020 stout=46/218760020
copy: STATUS 2
doexec: ls -lRi
.:
total 12
218760020 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 A
218764536 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 1 Sep 29 14:45 B -> A
218760034 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 C
218760040 -rw-r--r--. 1 user user 7 Sep 29 14:45 D
```

Comment: `open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT);`?!?  Aww, come on.  At least fix *that* bug...  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oops! Right you are. I saw that bug when I was on mobile but forgot it when I was refactoring the code on my desktop.

Comment: If `destination` is a directory, the code fails spectacularly. And don't just say `failed to open`. Please strerror the reason. –

Comment: @user58697 I had the same problem that blocked me, do you have any idea how to fix this...

Comment: @elfii I've updated my answer to add code for handling the second arg if it's a directory.

Comment: @CraigEstey i ve been strugling with this, you saved my life thanks.

Comment: @elfii You're quite welcome. Glad to help. Happy Programming!

Comment: @CraigEstey the only problem is when the ``source file`` is the same as ``destination``, it returns an empty file (I want it to return the ``destination file`` with the same content of the ``source file``)

Comment: @elfii I've updated my answer to handle source/destination collisions.

Comment: @CraigEstey I really apreciate your help and your explanation, i did learn many things from this post.

Comment: @CraigEstey i get the same problem in the **last update**, 
**If DESTINATION exists and is a directory, the source files will be copied there.**

Comment: @elfii See my latest update

Comment: @CraigEstey, your explanation helped me a lot.
The only problem I encounter is the case of multiple input files, I see that you added this functionality in your last edit, but I can't adapt it with my program,
What should i add so it can be fixed ?
I added my code in EDIT. (i can expalain if some things are ambiguous in my code )
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

> If DESTINATION exists and is a file, it is overwritten. If DESTINATION exists and is a directory, the source files will be copied there.

The easiest way to address this is to check how `open` failed`:

```
    int fd2 = open(argv[2], O_RDWR|O_CREAT);  
    if (fd2 < 0) {
        if (errno != EISDIR) {
            // It is a real failure. Log it, and quit
            fprintf("Opening %s: %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        // argv[2] names a directory. Act acordingly.
```

*Acting accordingly* depends on the precise spec. Consider a scenario:

```
> mkdir foo
> copy bar/baz/blah foo
```

As a result, one may expect a destination to be `foo/blah`. Another may expect it to be `foo/bar/baz/blah`.

In any case, you shall construct - according to the spec - the true destination filename from `argv[1]` relative to `argv[2]`, and open it for writing. Few calls to `mkdir` may also be required.